# Tracking sends event from within app exchange > query studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, reporting, data

I'm trying to access send data from within a sql ui. We have 'QueryStudio' under app exchange which let's me query data extension tables. E.g.

```
select AccountId
from Contact_Salesforce
```

Our data extensions appear to be user scoped tables that were set up for us.

I'd liek to include sends data here. If I navigate to e.g. `email studio > tracking > sends` I can select a campaign and see a report of summary data along with a clickable 'total sent' link which then drills down into a report with `subscriber_key` and `send_date`

My question is, this 'send event' data, does it exist in a pre built schema I can query within QueryStudio? Is there a sql interface to access this data rather than via the navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called data view. There is a number of them available, and the ones you would normally look at are:

- Sent
- Open
- Click
- Job

While the first 3 are global, the Job data view is BU specific. You can see all the data views and their respective fields in [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5).

[Mateusz Dabrowski](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/91679/mateusz-d%C4%85browski) has some good examples, along with queries, in his article, which can be [found here](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-config-system-data-views/).